# Aw Snap Error: Chrome crashing on exporting to csv using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, csv

I am trying to export a datatable to csv using c# code, in my asp.net website. The browser crashes after loading for sometime. It works fine in my local machine. However, when I deploy it on a server and try exporting, I get the "aw snap" error. Can someone please help?

Here is my C# code:

```
string csvfileName = FieldName + "_" + @"AnalysisReport_" + Session["TableName"].ToString() + ".csv";

            string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/" + csvfileName);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@fileName))
            {
                Common.ToCSV("*mydatatable*", writer, true);
            }

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + csvfileName);
            Response.WriteFile(fileName);
            Response.Flush();
            File.Delete(@fileName);
            Response.End();
```

The button to export to excel is placed inside an update panel. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried on any other browser?

Comment: Tried with IE 11. Application hangs there too

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a request ajax to load the event like that. You can try or remove the update panel for this component or add a trigger like that:

```
 <Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonThatFireExcel" />
 </Triggers>
```

The reason is because your page need to do a full request for the sever instead of do a partial request like the normal request of the update panel.

Besides that, I would consider to use text/csv instead of application/csv.

Comment: I have the trigger added already. I tried changing the MIME type to text/csv. No luck.